# Kafka producer unable to find the classes when called from Method annotated with @Async

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

`Unable to construct Kafka Producer in springboot application when published from Method annotated with @Async,

```
@Async
public void publishMessage()
{
 retrives data from DB and send the constructed message to Kafka using Kafka Template;
}
```

Producer Configuration like,

```
@Configuration 
public class ProducerConfig{
@Bean 
public KafkaTemplate<String, SpecificRecord> kafkaTemplate() 
{ 
ProducerFactory<String, SpecificRecord> producerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>( getBaseProducerSettings());  // getBaseProducerSettings() returns basic OAUTH     authentication                        
props and basic props return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory); 
}
}
```

When producer send method call initiated from @Async method, throwing errors for the classes which are not loaded by Application Classloader.
Example error message,

```
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: No LoginModule found for org.apache.kafka.common.security.oauthbearer.OAuthBearerLoginModule
```

Another error message,

```
org.apache.kafka.common.config.ConfigException: Invalid value org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer for configuration key.serializer: Class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer could not be found.
```

Required dependencies are already in the class path.
NOTE: Fully qualified class names are provided as string "" in the producer configuration.

Any help, on how to load the classes in Thread context which not loaded by Application Context.
`

Comment: For the latter errors, don't use strings. Use `StringSerializer.class` and `OAuthBearerLoginModule.class`, for example. Also, KafkaTemplate.send is already asynchronous, you should not need to annotate the method.

Comment: Also, if you want to "consume from database, and send to Kafka", ideally you'd use existing tools like Debezium

Comment: Thank you. I need to use @Async method in our API, Users are not expecting the response immediately and also our service get huge number of requests. so we don't want to block the user, we also run some additional checks before sending to kafka.I will look into it how to set the .class instead of passing class name in string.

Comment: As mentioned, `KafkaTemplate.send` is already async. You could also use Spring Webflux instead for fully ReactiveX based code.

Comment: Tried to pass OAuthBearerLoginModule.class into sasl.jaas.config property, but there is no way to pass it as without String along with config properties.            properties.put("sasl.jaas.config", jaasConfig);

Comment: SASL config needs to be a string, but you can still use Class.forName at runtime to verify the class exists on the classpath, separately from putting into properties.. Regardless, what version of spring-kafka are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed the issue after changing my Executor from Executors.newWorkStealingPool() to new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();

Seems there is different class loader policy when using Executors.newWorkStealingPool.